# How to insert several NSManageObjects in a one to many relationship?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have from one side the `NSManagedObject event` that has a relationship one to many with the `Entity Contacts`.My app downloads contacts from the server, once all the contacts are downloaded I want to save them in CoreData keeping the relationship. Im wondering if I can save them in one go. All the contacts in an NSArray, `contactsWeb`, and push them into Core Data or I have to save each one of them like this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];

for(int i = 0; [contactsWeb count]; i++){

NSManagedObject *contact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:context];

[contact setValue:[contactsWeb objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"text"];
[contact setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"date"];

[[event mutableSetValueForKey:@"toContacts"]addObject:contact];
 NSError *error;
if(![context save:&error]){
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving a managed object context means that *all changes* in the context are saved to the persistent store (or to the parent context, in the case of nested contexts). So you can (and should) save the context "in one go" after all contacts have been inserted and the relationships been set.

*Remark:* If you create managed object subclasses `Contacts` and `Event` for your entities, your code can be simplified to

```
Contacts *contact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:context];
contact.text = [contactsWeb objectAtIndex:i];
contact.date = [NSDate date];
[event addToContactsObject:contact];
```

The managed object subclasses can be created in Xcode: Select the entities in the Core Data model editor and choose "Editor -> Create NSManagedObject subclass ..." from the menu.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I wanted to do is to save the whole array of new contacts in one go. What you posted is the same thing Im doing but with Subclasses.

Comment: @DavidShaikh: I don't understand your comment. I have said in the first paragraph of my answer that saving the context always saves everything. - The following remark is only a suggestion how to simplify your code, but is completely independent of your "save" question.

Comment: @DavidShaikh: I do hope that my last comment did not sound rude. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Ok, so you mean that I should create 10 NSManagedObject, set the relationship, and when I save the context all the objects will be stored correctly, is that correct?

Comment: @DavidShaikh: yes, exactly.